# How can I read informations on the stack memory?

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I have this code that is vulnerable to buffer overflow attack because if the user types an argument less than 16, the program prints more informations then It should.
In this case I define 3 buf (buf, buf2 and buf3) that are stored in the stack (contiguously?).
But why the program print random values instead of printing the values of buff2 that is allocated next to buff (I guess)?
Aren't they stored contiguously in memory?
I thought the program gives me some 1 values that are stored in buff2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 16

unsigned char *isThisVulnerable(unsigned char* src, int size)
{
    unsigned char* retval = (unsigned char*)malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned char));
    return memcpy((void*)retval, (const void*)src, (size_t)size);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size = SIZE, i = SIZE, k = 0;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        size = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    unsigned char buf2[size];
    unsigned char buf[size];
    unsigned char buf3[size];

    for(k=0;k<size;k++){
        buf[k] = 0;
        buf2[k] = 1;
        buf3[k] = 2;
    }
    
    unsigned char *result = (unsigned char*)isThisVulnerable(buf, i);
    printf("%02X", result[0]);
    for(k=1;k<i;k++)
    {
        if(k%16 == 0)
            printf("\n");
        else if(k%4 == 0)
            printf("\t");
        printf("%02X", result[k]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

I tried to pass as input different values but it prints all 0.
I expected it to print the values of buff2 which should be saved next to buf.

Comment: It depends on your platform, your compiler, the version of your compiler, compiler flags and possibly some other factors. You need to look at the generated assembly code and/or debug your code at assembly level with your debugger.

Comment: *"Aren't they stored contiguously in memory?* Nothing in the language standard says that the variables have to be stored in a specific order, or in a specific place. So we don't know. Some compilers add special padding between the variables in debug mode to help detect (minor) buffer overflows.